# Падает соединение с базой данных mysql

Tags: mysql

есть сайт php+mysql, большую часть времени он работает нормально, раз в несколько часов и иногда минут в логе ошибок сайта появляются строки

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/www-root/data/root/site/n.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/www-root/data/root/site/n.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /var/www/www-root/data/root/site/n.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in /var/www/www-root/data/root/site/n.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=147423 in /var/www/www-root/data/root/site/n.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/www-root/data/root/site/n.php on line 123
```

В браузер понятно ничего не приходит. Длительность отсутствия подключения примерно 2сек, дальше все работает опять нормально

в строке 123 происходит подключение в базе данных ($dblocation = 'localhost')
$dbcnx = mysqli_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname);

php 7.4.3 (native)
от нагрузки появление этой ошибки вроде как не зависит, что это может быть?

Answer (score 1):

проблема была в малом количестве свободной оперативки, при достижении лимита mysql перезагружалась, что длилось примерно 2 сек. И все запросы в эти 2 секунды имели "PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect()...."